# Python: concatenate many dictionaries with shared keys (in a JSON) into one large dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am running many simulations, each of which appends a data dictionary to one base JSON file, as such:

```
{"Hnet": 0.047545953331778974,"Kabs": 0.4834911581175083, "t": 0.05}
{"Hnet": 0.8080405956760083, "Kabs": 0.187428764511818, "t": 0.15}
...
```

At the end, I would like to concatenate all these separate dictionaries using the shared keys into only one dictionary, having these shared keys, so that I can then convert into a dataframe and look at the consolidated data. How do I go about it?

Comment: What does this have to do with `pandas`?  Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  The goal is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the dictionaries in a list, then convert the list to a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dicts =[{"Hnet": 0.047545953331778974,"Kabs": 0.4834911581175083, "t": 0.05},
                {"Hnet": 0.8080405956760083, "Kabs": 0.187428764511818, "t": 0.15},
                {"Hnet": 0.2983472834234521, "Kabs": 0.234872398473289, "t": 0.10},
                {"Hnet": 0.012937281973213913, "Kabs": 0.384849210587031, "t": 0.05}]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)

print(df)
```

Your output will then be:

```
       Hnet      Kabs     t
0  0.047546  0.483491  0.05
1  0.808041  0.187429  0.15
2  0.298347  0.234872  0.10
3  0.012937  0.384849  0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to consolidate the values based on the keys using python. The right way will be putting the values in the list and it will be easier to use them later as dataframe.

```
>>> with open('sample.json') as f:
...      data = json.loads(f.read())
... 
>>> data
[{'Hnet': 0.047545953331778974, 'Kabs': 0.4834911581175083, 't': 0.05}, {'Hnet': 0.8080405956760083, 'Kabs': 0.187428764511818, 't': 0.15}]
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> final_data = defaultdict(list)
>>> for row in data:
...     for k, v in row.items():
...         final_data[k].append(v)
... 
>>> final_data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Hnet': [0.047545953331778974, 0.8080405956760083], 'Kabs': [0.4834911581175083, 0.187428764511818], 't': [0.05, 0.15]})
>>>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the code. What does `defaultdict(list)` do here?

Comment: @ap21 `defaultdict` acts as a default entry value for non-existing keys. That means if you are trying to access a key that doesn't exist in your dictionary it looks for default value. In our case empty `list` will be returned.